# Etsy API pagination - Don't know how to access to other pages

Tags: php, api, curl, oauth, etsy

So, I had issue because I don't have OAuth 1, so to access to ETSY API I had to struggle.

finally I have this :

My function __construct() :

parent::__construct();

```
    $this->allowForUser();
    $this->etsyDb = new EtsyordersModel;
    
    $this->client = new Etsy([
        'identifier'            =>      getApp()->getConfig('identifier'),
        'secret'                =>      getApp()->getConfig('secret'),
        'scope'                 =>      'listings_r transactions_r',
        'callback_uri'          =>      'http://*****-*****.loc/etsyapp/next',
        'access_token'          =>      getApp()->getConfig('access_token'),
        'access_token_secret'   =>      getApp()->getConfig('access_token_secret'),
    ]);
```

And here is how I get the url to access my JSON with the result :

```
        $key = rawurlencode($oauthtoken) . "&" . rawurlencode($tokensecret);

        $method = "GET";
        $baseurl = "https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/shops/24749672/receipts/";
        $nonce = "1234";
        $timenow = time();
        $oauthversion = '1.0';

        $paramstring = "oauth_consumer_key=" . $oauthconsumerkey . "&oauth_nonce=" . $nonce . "&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1" . "&oauth_timestamp=" . $timenow . "&oauth_token=" . $clientsecret .  "&oauth_version=" . $oauthversion;

        // 
        // Signature GET to retrieve signature OAuth
        $encodeurl = $method . "&" . rawurlencode($baseurl) . "&" . rawurlencode($paramstring);

        $signature = hash_hmac( 'sha1', $encodeurl, $key, TRUE );
        $signature = base64_encode( $signature );
 
        // url JSON shop ETSY
        $curlurl = $baseurl . "?" . $paramstring . "&oauth_signature=" . $signature;
        
        // get JSON content in $orders
        $orders = file_get_contents($curlurl);
```

And so I get my JSON :

[image]

I got 90++ items, but because of the pagination, it show me only 25 items.

I tried to add `active?limit=100&offset=0` to my $baseurl (at the end of it, as parameter for signature calculation) but it say `oauth_problem=signature_invalid&amp;`. I tried to put it on the `$paramstring`
instead, but same result.
How can I have all my result shown, or how can I access to page 2, 3, etc... of the pagination?

I am on PHP 7.4, XAMPP (one of the last version), I don't have OAuth 1 so I used a combination of package Y0lk\OAuth1 and thephpleague\oauth1-client.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: _“I tried to add `active?limit=100&offset=0` to my $baseurl (at the end of it) but it doesn't work“_ - where exactly did you try that? If you did not include those additional parameters in the calculation of the signature, then it would not be surprising this “didn’t work”. (Please go read [ask] - “doesn’t work” is not a proper way to describe a problem to begin with.)

Comment: Thank for your reply, I'll try to improve all this in futur post. So I edited the question to add that I added `active?limite=100&offset=0` in the calculation of the signature.

Comment: Go check the implementation details in the relevant documentation. The signature calculation is often dependent on all parameters being in alphabetical order, regarding their names.

Comment: Sorry for late answer, but I confirm that if you want it to work, you have to put parameters in alphabetical order. Thank you @CBroe.